# Discrepancy REG QUERY local vs remote computer batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, remote-registry

I'm writing a batch script to update a software package (uninstall old
version/ install new one). This needs to be done over the network as
there are 500 PCs to update. One of the first steps before uninstalling is checking wether that software is installed or not. In order to check that
I query the registry:

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\A.E.T Europe B.V."
```

This query gives adecuate results when running in local (for testing purposes), but when I run it remotely (they way it will be
ran) returns wrong results.

```
reg query "\\I301\HKLM\SOFTWARE\A.E.T Europe B.V."
```

returns 0 if i run that line locally. But if I log into I301 and run the
query locally returns 1, being the truth that A.E.T Europe B.V. shows up under the Wow6432Node branch in the windows registry.

Why is that???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is on 64-bit Windows just the key

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\A.E.T Europe B.V.
```

but no key

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\A.E.T Europe B.V.
```

the reason for the different result is caused most likely by which version of `reg.exe` is executed from batch file or command line.

The key is not found if 64-bit `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe` is executed on processing the batch file or running the command by 64-bit `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` on using the line

```
reg query "\\I301\HKLM\SOFTWARE\A.E.T Europe B.V."
```

But the key is found if 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\reg.exe` is executed on processing the batch file or running the command by 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` on using the line

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\A.E.T Europe B.V."
```

because for the 32-bit applications the registry access to `HKLM\SOFTWARE` is redirected to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` by registry redirector.

Check both possible key locations:

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 1 I301 >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Computer with name I301 is not available in network.
    goto :EOF
)

%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "\\I301\HKLM\SOFTWARE\A.E.T Europe B.V." >nul 2>&1
if not errorlevel 1 goto Installed
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "\\I301\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\A.E.T Europe B.V." >nul 2>&1
if not errorlevel 1 goto Installed

echo A.E.T Europe B.V. is not installed.
goto :EOF

:Installed
echo A.E.T Europe B.V. is installed already.
```

See also the Microsoft documentation pages:

- [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)
- [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details)
- [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys)

Answer (score 1):

Good answer by Mofi. On 64 bit systems you might also consider using

/reg:32 & /reg:64
See REG QUERY /?

You can sometimes get into trouble if you are launching CMD.exe from another app. If that app is a 32 bit app it will launch the 32 bit version of CMD.exe

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mofi and RGuggisberg,

Found out about everything Mofi said (and RGuggisberg complemented) later on the day. Since I couldn't make it work I tried checking for the Uninstall entry in the registry, thinking it would be there and only there. After getting again similar results I did a bit more googling and found out about Windows having two trees in the registry: one for 32 bits applications and another for 64 bits. The hint was given by:

- http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html

At the end it shows up the two options that RGuggisber mentions /reg:32 & /reg:64. Looked them up and found about the existence of both registries.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Tried same query (for uninstalled) BUT using /reg:64 and found the key I was looking for. Tried with /reg:32 and indeed could not find it. The machine I was running the script from runs Windows 7 32-bits. The remote machine Windows 8.1 64 bits.